# How do i hook up this 2-digit 7-segment display

Tags: 7segmentdisplay, pinout

I have a 2-digit 7-segment display.
I'm not able to determine the common anode pins even after consulting the [datasheet](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.icchip.info%2Fdatasheet%2FLTD383E-R2.pdf&ei=v1UmVK3KMo7kuQSHt4LYDw&usg=AFQjCNFRI7_f6-BoVQylfR5vvlaOtW7g4Q&sig2=6Ce1x3dNul86o3Sk630kdQ&bvm=bv.76247554,d.c2E/).
Where are the anode pins?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasheet clearly shows that the Anode connection is pin 4.  If you look closely at the front of the display, you should be able to see the decimal points.  The datasheet shows that when looking at the front of the display with the decimal points at the bottom, the bottom left pin is pin 1.  Just like an IC.

You can test the display with a small power supply or 9V battery.  Use a 1k resistor between the power (+) line and pin 4 of the display.  Touching the (-) power lead to each of the segment pins should cause that segment to illuminate.

Comment: Thank you both! There's actually a little wedge to indicate the bottom right side of the chip. I only noticed it after scrutinizing the datasheet. TYVM

Answer (score 1):

The common anode — for *both* digits — is pin 4.

In other words, this is not a multiplexed display — you have direct control over all 14 LEDs.

Both the internal diagram on page 2 and the pinout table on page 3 make this patently clear, so I don't know why you found this confusing.